# Using Multiple If Statements with While Loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write a while loop that goes through a certain list looking for certain substrings. It will find words with those substrings and print out those strings.

Here is a example that works perfectly but for only one word:

```
lista = ['applepie','appleseed','bananacake','bananabread']

i = 0
z = len(lista)
while i < z:
    if ('pie' in lista[0+i]) == True:
        print(lista[0+i])
        break
    i = i  + 1
else:
    print('Not There Yet')
```

This prints out applepie (which is what is desired!).

How do I go about fixing this while loop to add in multiple constraints?

I'm trying to do this:

```
lista = ['applepie','appleseed','bananacake','bananabread']

i = 0
z = len(lista)
while i < z:
    if ('pie' in lista[0+i]) == True:
        print(lista[0+i])
    if ('cake' in lista[0+1]) == True:
        print(lista[0+i])
    i = i  + 1
else:
    print('Not There Yet')
```

This prints out:
applepie
Not There Yet

When I want this to print out:
applepie
bananacake

I used multiple 'if' statements, because I know if I want to use an 'elif', it will only run if the first 'if' statement is false.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `'cake' in lista[0+1]` should be `'cake' in lista[i]` (not sure why you're adding 0... but it should be `i`, not `1`)

Comment: Why are you doing lists like this rather than a regular `for` loop?!?

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues smallish issues and I think one larger. The first of the two small ones are what Nick and Brenden noted above. The second is your conditional. It should be <= as opposed to the < you used.

The larger seems that you're having a problem conceptualizing the actual workings. For that, let me suggest you [step through it here](https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/visualize#code=lista+%3D+%5B'applepie','appleseed','bananacake','bananabread'%5D%0A%0Ai+%3D+0%0Az+%3D+len(lista)%0Awhile+i+%3C%3D+z%3A%0A++++if+('pie'+in+lista%5Bi%5D)+%3D%3D+True%3A%0A++++++++print(lista%5B0%2Bi%5D)%0A++++if+('cake'+in+lista%5Bi%5D)+%3D%3D+True%3A%0A++++++++print(lista%5B0%2Bi%5D)%0A++++i+%3D+i++%2B+1%0Aelse%3A%0A++++print('Not+There+Yet')&mode=display&raw_input=&curInstr=23)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to go through a list of conditions. It will evaluate to `True` when the condition is first met and `False` if it never happens. If you combine that with a regular python `for` loop, it will be nice a succinct:

```
lista = ['applepie','appleseed','bananacake','bananabread']
words = ['pie', 'cake']

for food in lista:
    if any(word in food for word in words):
        print(food)
```

It prints:

```
applepie
bananacake
```

You can also so the same thing as a list comprehension to get a list of words that match:

```
lista = ['applepie','appleseed','bananacake','bananabread']
words = ['pie', 'cake']

found = [food for food in lista if any(word in food for word in words)]
# ['applepie', 'bananacake']
```

Generally speaking, Python discourages you from using indices in loops unless you really need to. It tends to be error prone and harder to read.